# What's an efficient way of removing seeds from citrus fruits?

Tags: utensils, citrus, juicing

My application is for juicing but I guess it would apply to fruit salads as well.

I have an auger-style crushing juicer and roughly remove seeds I see before ramming the orange/lemon/... pieces down the juicer chute. Unfortunately a few seeds escape detection and as I like to put the pulp back into the juice, I get a few crushed seeds in the juice. Not nice.

Are there any accepted utensils/techniques for removing the seeds beyond probing each piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found so far (for juicing) is to just thoroughly squeeze the pieces between thumb and forefinger over the flat part of the juicer chute so the juice flows down the chute and the seeds pop out for removal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have a twin-screw masticating juicer ([an older model Angel juicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Y1A0BO)) and although the seeds come out quite chewed up, I wouldn't want to drink them and we've never put the pulp back into the juice.

One possibility that comes to mind is to cut the oranges, etc., into pieces and separate out the pieces that have seeds from those that don't.  Run the seedless ones through first and save that pulp to put into the juice.  Then run the pieces with seeds through and toss that pulp.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Solved with apple seed remover. Just cut out the the middle part with it, and problem solved.

Comment: Which middle part? In my experience, lemon seeds are found within the wedges. And if you remove most of the center, including large parts of the wedges, it seems like a wasteful solution, even if we assume that there are no seeds in the outer wedge portions.

Answer (score 0):

With many citrus fruits, altering the way you cut them already helps - eg with many lemons, if you slice the sides off instead of cutting it into slices, you get all the seeds in the remaining centerpieces.

The fraction of pieces that still have seeds in them might be best processed with a food mill (mouli).